# How to use two or more NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

My app use CoreData. It has a UISegmentedControl and a tableview. The UISegmentedControl is used to update tableview based on different criteria.

The 1st option of UISegmentedControl will show all data in a single tableview section. So I use the following code in - (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController

```
frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                          managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] 
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                          cacheName:@"Root"];
```

The 2nd option will show data in multiple tableview section. So I need NSSortDescriptor and set sectionNameKeyPath.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"city" 
                                                             ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = nil;
frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                          managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] 
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"city" 
                                          cacheName:@"Root"];
```

Because sectionNameKeyPath is different which each of them need different NSSortDescriptor, I assume I need two different NSFetchedResultsController.

The code I use to reload tableview:

```
- (void) touchDownAtSegmentIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex{

NSPredicate *predicate;
NSError *error;    

[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];

if(segmentIndex == 0)
{

}
else if(segmentIndex == 1)
{

}
else
{
    return;
}

[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];
[[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error];
[[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

Anyone can provide me a sample of code that use two NSFetchedResultsController. 
Thank you.

**SOLUTION:**

In addition from @iTukker idea, I added more checking before returning `fetchedResultsController`.  Without this checking, this method will return `fetchedResultsController` instead of executing `switch .. case ..` statement.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController {

.....
    if ((fetchedResultsController!= nil) && [self.segmentChanged isEqualToString:@"false"])
    return fetchedResultsController;
.....

    if (frc == nil) {
        switch (segmentendControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
           case 0: {
               frc = ... //first frc
               [frc retain];
               break;
           }
           case 1: {
               frc = ... //second frc
               [frc retain];
               break;
           }
        }
    }

....

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would do is something like this, assuming that frc is a instance variable of your controller

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController {
   if (frc == nil) {
      switch (segmentendControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
         case 0: {
             frc = ... //first frc
             [frc retain];
             break;
         }
         case 1: {
             frc = ... //second frc
             [frc retain];
             break;
         }
      }
   }

   return frc;
}
```

And when the value of your segmentedController changes

```
[frc release];
frc = nil;
[tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this makes sence

Comment: Thanks. I assume your answer is using one fetchedResultsController. I remember do similar thing. It only work when the app first load. But it doesn't respond when segmentedControl clicked. I put `[tableView reloadData]` in `(void) touchDownAtSegmentIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex{`

Comment: I notice you use `[frc retain];` in fetchedResultsController and `[frc release]` when segmentedController change. I will give it a try. Thx.

Comment: Yes, one frc, in your viewsController .h you have something like NSFetchedResultsController *frc. I would use the event  UIControlEventValueChanged to reset the frc and reload table data. And yes, you use retain (when not using ARC of course) since you create a new frc in the fetchedResultsController method when it was nil. And I also assume that f.i. in the numberOfSectionsInTableView: you do return [self fetchedResultsController].sections

Comment: Just to be clear, this is important, in all your tableview datasource callbacks like numberOfRowsInsetions, etc. you always use [self fetchedResultsController] and not reference frc directly!

Comment: It didn't work. I put `NSLog` inside `(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController`. The log show that it only called once. It is never executed again every time the segmentedcontrol change. Perhaps I really need more than one `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: I am sure this works, and you really need one frc. I use this all the time. Are you sure that you implemented the datasource callbacks for you tableview correclty? I.e for instance [self fetchedResultsController].sections? This should already hit your log statement

Comment: Here is what I use. I think there no problem with the delegate functions. 
`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
{ 
    return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}`

Comment: The sections show properly. The problem is when the segmentedcontrol change, the tableview data is updated. But the segment number remain the same. I think the problem is in `(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController`, it is called once. I know it by using NSLog. So the `switch .. case ..` in this method will never work, it always 0.

Comment: Your callbacks should be like: return [[self fetchedResultsController ] sections] count]; You are using the variable fetchedResultsController directly, but you should call the method ([self fetchedResultsController ]) instead, otherwise you wont hit the logic which is in there

Comment: I added `self`, but still not work. `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
{ 
    return [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] count];
}`. When `[tableView reload]` is called, it doesn't call `numberOfSectionsInTableView` ? Could it be that because this method was called once?

Comment: No, if you call [self.tableView reloadData] the numberOfSections will be called. Just start debugging, put some breakpoints in your code, you have something wrong somewhere.

Comment: You are correct. I got `numberOfSectionsInTableView` called each time `[[self tableView] reloadData];` is called. I will take time to debug now.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer lead to the final solution.